# What is a 1/2 way ssl request

Tags: https

What does it mean when an application calls another application via 2 way SSL.
Does it mean that an external application calls another application via https and also receives a https response.
Similarly if it was one way SSL, does it mean it sends a https request but the response will be http.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea of 1-way/2-way SSL from?  And an HTTPS request is just HTTP over SSL, so the request and response will be HTTP, just encrypted in both directions.